# How to open a .xib from a button click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

Can anyone please give me some idea how can I open a new .xib from a UIButton? I meant that if I click on a button it will open a new window.

Answer (score 4):

Link the button's touch up inside event to an IBAction method in your UIViewController subclass. In that method, instantiate a new UIViewController with your xib using:

```
YourViewControllerClass *vc= [[YourViewControllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourXibName" bundle:nil];
```

Then if you have a nav controller you want to push it onto:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc release];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NewTableController *newTableController=[[NewTableController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewTableController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newTableController animated:YES];
```